# Telerik MVC3 Grid - is it possible to use Template and ClientTemplate at the same time?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, telerik-grid

Is it possible to use a Template and a ClientTemplate at the same time?

I want to do a bool check in the Template but don't know how to pass it to the checkbox in the ClientTemplate when there is no binding.

```
    @(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.Item)
     .Name("Grid")
     .Columns(column =>
       column.Template(x => x.ItemId.Equals(Model.Id))
             .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' checked='<#=????? #>' disabled />");
    })
```

Maybe there's another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular case, you don't have to use `Template`. You can use the embedded databound functionality (as mentioned by Daniel) of the ClientTemplate to achieve what you want,

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.Item)
  .Name("Grid")
  .Columns(column =>
    column.ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' checked='<#=ItemId == " + Model.Id + "#>' disabled />");
})
```

This way you passed the variable `Model.Id` from the server, while the actual comparison is down using Javascript at the client side.

Answer (score 1):

Template is used for server binding, while ClientTemplate is used for ajax or web service binding. If you are using server binding, ClientTemplate is not used. If you are using ajax binding, Template is not used. With ClientTemplate, you can use <#= #> to embed databound expressions in a similar way to server side Template.

```
.ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' checked='<#= (ItemID == Id) #>' disabled />")
```

What you put in a conditional is limited. I have been able to successfully use a bool and an int comparison, but not a string comparison.

Comment: However, in this case `Id` is not a property of `Model.Item`, so it won't be available at the client side.